# Symfony2 and Doctrine2 : populate form with two Entity (a complicated scenario)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-forms

I have 5 entities:

- User,
- Person,
- UserAffiliation,
- PersonAffiliation and
- Affiliation

Here is the schema:

[image]

**Some details:**

- A WebUser is a Person who is registered to the website. For each Webuser, there is a person ID.
- A person can be a web user, an author etc.
- Each WebUser has 0 or more affiliations. Those affiliations were created by this WebUser and linked in the able UserAffiliations.
- The WebUser can also link the affiliations he createed to a person (if the person is an author) and the Entity PersonAffiliation will be populated.

I am trying now to give the possibility to the webuser to assign an affiliation to an author (person). For that, the I have:

- In the Entity Person

  ```
  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonAffiliation", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist", "remove"})

  protected $affiliations;
  ```
- In the PersonAffiliation

  ```
  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="affiliations")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")

  protected $person;

  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Affiliation", inversedBy="person_affiliations")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="affiliation_id", referencedColumnName="id")

  protected $affiliation;
  ```
- In the Entity User:

  ```
  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserAffiliation", mappedBy="user")

  protected $affiliations;


  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")

  protected $person;
  ```
- In the Entity UserAffiliation

  ```
  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="affiliations")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")

  protected $user;


  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Affiliation", inversedBy="user_affiliations")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="affiliation_id", referencedColumnName="id")

   protected $affiliation;
  ```

In the form, I am doing the next:

```
$builder->add('affiliations', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:PersonAffiliation',
            'query_builder' => function($em) use ($person){
            return $em->createQueryBuilder('pa')->where('pa.person_id = :id')->setParameter('id', $person->getId());
        },
            'property'    => 'affiliation',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ));
```

But all this is not working properly as I would like.

**Explanation**: When I try to add a new affiliation, it is only added for the WebUser and I can't link it through the form to the author (Person).

Do you have an idea on how to resolve this, or maybe a good tutorial?

Comment: Do you have a UserFormType as well as an embedded PersonFormType?

Comment: @Cerad, I have a SubmissionAffiliationFormType and a SubmissionAuthorFormType. The SubmissionAffiliationFormType for creating new Affiliations for a specific user and the SubmissionAuthorFormType for linking the affiliations to a specific person (author).

Comment: It's probably just me but I'm not understanding the problem.  Where does $person come from?  Is it always the user or is the user trying to give affiliations to another person?  Do you have something live that we could click on and see the problem?  Having a UserAffliation as well as a PersonAfflition just seems wrong considering that Users are always Persons.  But that is just instincts and reflects my not understanding the goal.

Comment: @Cerad, In fact, a person can be anything, a user, an author or whatewer. The difference is that the user is used to login in to the website (he is a registered person). The user has his own affiliation, but can also create affiliations (that's why the table UserAffiliations exists). When the user creates an author (another person), this user can assign affiliations to htis author (person) and he can create new affiliations or choose affiliations he created from the table UserAffiliations. I don't have anything online for the moment but can give more details on the problem if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be handled in the Entity1Controller.php:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
  $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $form = $this->createForm(new Entity1Type()
     ,null,array('attr' => array('securitycontext' => $securityContext)));
  $form->bind($request);

  if ($form->isValid()){
    $data = $form->getData();
    $entity1id = $data->getId();
    $entity2id = $data->getEntity2Id();
    $entity1medicaid=$data->getMedicaidID();
    $entity1=$em->getRepostiory('projectBundle:Entity1')->findOneById($entity1id);
    $entity2=$em->getRepository('projectprojectBundle:Entity2')->findOneById($entity2id);
    if (null === $entity1){
      $entity1=new entity1();
      $entity1->setEntity2id($entity2id);
      $entity1->setID($entity1id);
    }
    if (null === $entity2){
      $entity2=new entity2();
      $entity2->setID($entity2id);
    }
    $em->persist($entity1);
    $em->persist($entity2);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('entity1', array()));
  }

  return $this->render('Bundle:entity1:new.html.twig', array(
      'form'   => $form->createView()
     ,'attr' => array('securitycontext' => $securityContext
     )
  )
  );
}
```

You may also have to set cascade persist in your association mappings.  Entity1.yml:

```
project\projectBundle\Entity\Entity1:
    type: entity
    table: entity1
    repositoryClass: project\projectBundle\Entity\Entity1Repository
    fields:
        id:
            type: bigint
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        property:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
    manyToMany:
        entity2:
            targetEntity: entity2
            mappedBy: entity1
            cascade: ["persist"]
```

In theory, symfony will make entity2 under the hood, making the second if null clause unnecessary, but that always bothers me, so I prefer to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Well if this form is binding the collection to a WebUser Entity is because you are passing in to the Form creation in the Controller an object of such class, it means:

```
$webUser = new WebUser();

$this->createForm(new SubmissionAffiliationFormType(), $webUser);
```

or you are delegating the decision of which class to use to Symfony Forms by not setting the DefaultOptions and telling explicitly the data_class it must be bind to:

```
class SubmissionAffiliationFormType extends AbstractType
{

    //...

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Person',
        );
    }
}
```